# iPhone 3GS locked to at&t. How do unlock it?

Tags: iphone, itunes, ios, error

I bought an iPhone 3GS, second hand, and I have now found out its on a AT&T network. I live in the UK, I can't get past the "Connect to iTunes" message. Even when I connect to iTunes it says:

> Phone not found. Please try again later.

I can't get into the settings on the phone either. Do I need to unlock the phone from AT&T? If so, how can I do that? If not, how can I get past the errors?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'll either have to get in contact with AT&T, pay a 3rd party to unlock it or jailbreak it.

If you're going to try and contact AT&T then you'll have to go to their website and fill out a form to start the dialogue. If you need a ZIP code Google the one for Grand Central or something.

The GiffGaff Unlockipedia is a good place to start when looking for a 3rd party to unlock the phone. http://giffgaff.com/unlock/apple-iphone-3g-phone

Not so up on the jailbreaking scene these days but Lifehacker is usually good for the information. http://lifehacker.com/5771943/how-to-jailbreak-your-iphone-the-always-up+to+date-guide-%5Bios-61%5D